# SymmetricException: Could not find the properties file

Tags: database, postgresql, symmetricds

I'm Configuring symmtricDS into my windows server for Postgresql Database synchronization.
Version : symmetric-server-3.7.28, 
Refering below URL for the configuration
http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-install

2.1. Installing SymmetricDS is completed. 
2.2. Creating and Populating Your Databases - completed.

But when i'm trying `"J:\SymetricDS\symmetric-server-3.7.28\conf>..\bin\sym --engine corp-000 --port 31445"` command under 2.3. Starting SymmetricDS session, getting below error

```
"org.jumpmind.symmetric.SymmetricException: Could not find the properties file"
```

[image]

But , command `"J:\SymetricDS\symmetric-server-3.7.28\conf>..\bin\sym"` is working fine and getting the port details like below.

```
J:\SymetricDS\symmetric-server-3.7.28\conf>..\bin\sym
Log output will be written to J:\SymetricDS\symmetric-server-3.7.28/logs/symmetr
ic.log
[startup] - SymmetricWebServer - About to start SymmetricDS web server on host:p
ort default:31445
[startup] - / - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[startup] - / - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'rest'
[startup] - SymmetricWebServer - Starting JMX HTTP console on port 31446
[startup] - SymmetricWebServer - Joining the web server main thread
HttpAdaptor version 3.0.1 started on port 31446
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties configuration file for the engine `corp-001` should be stored in `J:\SymetricDS\symmetric-server-3.7.28\engines` directory as explained in the [tutorial](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_node_properties_file).